# If a piecewise function has a sub-domain which is dense in the other, do any properties regarding continuity/discontinuity follow?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, differential-topology, piecewise-continuity

Let $f:S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
      g(x) & \text{if}\ x \in D, \\
      h(x) & \text{if}\ x \in S/D,
\end{cases}
$$

where $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $D \subset S$ is a dense subset of $S$. Are there any theorems regarding properties of $g,h$ and $f$'s continuity or discontinuity?

Comment: The indicator function mapping rationals to $1$ and irrationals to $0$ is continuous if you restrict the domain to the rationals, or to the irrationals, but nowhere continuous if the domain is $[0,1]$, for example. I'm not sure what else you could hope to find.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, then so is $g$.

Comment: (i) If $g$ is continuous and (ii) $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x)$ exist and $h(x) =\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x)$ for each $a\in S/D$, then $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Also, if $g$ is uniformly continuous and and $h(x) =\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x)$ for each $a\in S/D$, then $f$ is continuous.

Comment: In any case, $f$, which is the continuous extension of $g$, is unique, since you forced $D$ to be dense in $S$

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuous then $f|_D$ and $f|_{S\setminus D}$ i.e. $g$ and $h$ are continuous having $D$ and $S\setminus D$ endowed with subspace topologies. But the converse does not hold (take the characteristic function of $\mathbb{Q}$).

If $f, g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous then $f=g$ as restrictions of $f$ and $g$ to the dense subset $D$ are identical. 
 (Exercise: Let $f, g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be two continuous functions. Show that if $f|_D=g|_D$ then $f=g$. (***Hint***: $\{x:x\in X\  \text{and}\ f(x)=g(x)\}$  is closed.)) Moreover you can deduce that if $\mathcal{F}$ is the set of all continuous functions $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ then $|\mathcal{F}|\leq \mathbb{|R|}^{|D|}$.